# Cannot start service explorer: oci runtime error using hypereldger cello

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, docker-container

Hi all I am using hyperledger cello framework to create blockchain containers

I have problem when I create chain with this error message:

```
ERROR: for explorer  Cannot start service explorer: oci runtime error:
container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused       
"process_linux.go:359: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:54: mounting 
\\\"/opt/cello/fabric-1.0/local/explorer-artifacts/config.json\\\" 
to rootfs
\\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/c0942a0b749ad436d6f4480fb43623dbd44575fd17f0adfcdbea9390df2c4d8c/merged\\\" 
at \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/c0942a0b749ad436d6f4480fb43623dbd44575fd17f0adfcdbea9390df2c4d8c/merged/blockchain-explorer/config.json\\\" 
caused \\\"not a directory\\\"\""

: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type
```

I already gave permission to docker

Comment: Please provide the command ur using to start the container.

Comment: i didn't write specific command for it i am using cello module to make blockchain containers i open container that have GUI that make container and get the logs

Answer (score 0):

i solved the problem

the problem with me is that the folder in /opt/cell which create from command

```
make setup-worker
```

the it's create folder config.json not file so run command again solve problem with me